# Do I have to release the nib's top level objects if I don't load the nib manually?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, memory-management

As I understand it, I do have to release the top level objects (including window, custom controller objects, ...) from my Nib file, if I load it programmatically by myself.

But do I have to care about them in an simple view-based application that has only one main nib file?

And would I have to care about them when having an view-based application that uses an UITabBarController and multiple Nib files?

Answer (score 2):

No. In all cases, the nibs are loaded once, and then unloaded when your app is closed - you don't have to manage the memory. There's no memory leak possible when you don't create more than one of a given object.